# What is the impedance of a Microchip PIC I/O Port configured as input when Vpin > Vdd?

Tags: pic, high-impedance

I'm using a PIC18F1320, and it is powered with VDD=4V.
There is an external power signal, with a higher value than VDD. 
The external signal is connected to the RB5 I/O port through a voltage divider:

- All internal pull-up resistors are disabled.
- Port is set as input via TRISBbits.RB5 = 1;

Under those circumstances, I expected the node P to be around **6.95V**. But instead I found it to be at **5.6V**.

This means that node P is leaking almost 35mA but:

- The node P is also connected to a MOSFET gate, whose leakage current is, according to specifications, 2uA.
- According to PIC18F1320 specifications, the leakage current of I/O ports configured as inputs is 1uA. But it also specifies that the test condition is "VDD < VPIN < VSS", which I'm not meeting.

My question is:

- What is the impedance of the input port when the input voltage is slightly over VDD?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLlwPJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]
You're outside the maximum absolute ratings, so nobody knows anything. As far as the manufacturer is concerned aliens are messing with your warp field coils.

Seriously though, most chips have a diode from their pins to Vdd, which is probably sinking your current.

Answer (score 3):

MOSFET gates are very sensitive to high voltages (if the gate oxide has a thickness of 20 nm, a voltage of 7 V results in a field strength of 350 kV/cm, which is likely to damage it; at 10 V, breakdown is likely).
So most chips have ESD protection diodes from ground and to V<sub>DD</sub> that are intended to clamp voltage spikes.

(Sometimes, input pins are designed to be 5V tolerant; in this case, the diode to V<sub>DD</sub> is omitted.)

As long as the diode to V<sub>DD</sub> does not turn on, you still get the high gate impedance. (This is why Microchip specifies "V<sub>DD</sub> + 0.3 V" in the absolute maximum ratings.)
But when the voltage goes higher, the diode conducts, and the voltage at the pin is clamped to V<sub>DD</sub> plus the forward voltage of the diode.
How large this is depends on the current, which is limited only by the resistor you have put in front of the pin.

Microchip's absolute maximum ratings also specify a clamp current. You should stay far away from that limit, so 35 mA is way too large; consider making the resistor high enough so that you get a few tens of µA at most. If that makes the signal too slow, you have to use a 'real' level shifter.

The input impedance of the pin itself is essentially that of the diode to V<sub>DD</sub>, but it's smaller than the series resistor which you need anyway, so that is your effective impedance.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the impedance of the input port when the input voltage is slightly over VDD?

practically zero: the clamping diodes is all there is.

that's why it is always a good practice to put a serial resistor (or a buffer if allowed) on pins that interact with the outside world.

Comment: Serial resistor I have. Buffer is what I want. Thanks for the hint.